# How does a program determine if the peer node is a bootnode or full node?

Tags: devp2p, bootnodes, rlpx

Looking at the DEVp2p protocol, I see that a peer can return info on capabilities ETH or SHH . I do not see in the protocol docs what those mean. How does a client discover if the peer is only implementing RLPx / Kademlia discovery, rather than the full Ethereum protocol?

Answer (score 2):

The [RLPx](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md) protocol suite consists of at least two protocols:

- The **Kademlia like discovery protocol**, that involves UDP packets that are simply signed by the nodes and not encrypted
- The RLPx/devp2p protocol, that involves encrypted TCP packets. This protocol requires a two-phase handshake. In the first phase the peers exchange the secret used to encrypt the messages, while in the latter they
  negotiate the capabilities (i.e. the devp2p subprotocols) that they support.

> Looking at the DEVp2p protocol, I see that a peer can return info on capabilities ETH or SHH

As already said during the initial RLPx/devp2p handshake (the Hello Message) the peers exchange the info on their capabilities, i.e. the devp2p wire sub-protocols and versions that they supports:

- [eth](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Wire-Protocol), ETH is the protocol used to exchange information about the blockchain (it has message types like GetBlocks,GetBlockHashes etc.)
- [shh](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper-Wire-Protocol), whisper
- (there are also other subprotocols, e.g. [les](https://github.com/paritytech/wiki/blob/master/Light-Ethereum-Subprotocol-(LES).md))

> How does a client discover if the peer is only implementing RLPx / Kademlia discovery, rather than the full Ethereum protocol?

That said, I think that either a bootnode does not implement/answer to devp2p messages.

Comment: The second bullet point for sub-protocols should be `shh` https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper#basic-design and not SSH.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you for pointing it out ^^. They are written in lower case (at least eth and shh) (as reported here https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/%C3%90%CE%9EVp2p-Wire-Protocol). 
SSH is secure shell :)